# How to apply array_map to a function which has more arguments in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I have a quite simple question, yet I cannot get a way around it. I'd like to walk through an array and change it's items with a function, then return a new array of the new values.

Here is my array:

```
$array = array('thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3');
```

This is my function:

```
function testing ($string, $to)
{
    retrun substr($string, 0, $to);
}
```

And I'd like to do the following:

```
array_map(testing($string, 2), $array);
```

The above statement is not working properly. Can anyone tell me how to make this `array_map` function to work as expected?

Comment: See the [documentation for `array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map). Pay attention to the examples. Also, you need to explain *exactly* what you mean by "not working properly" -- if we are to answer your question then we need to have something to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `array_map` an anonymous function that calls `testing`.

```
array_map(function($string){
    return testing($string, 2);
}, $array);
```